# How to deal with URLs that has been hotlinked?

Tags: cpanel, downtime, hotlinking

My website assets have been hot linked by many other websites. I doubt whether these are responsible for the downtimes on my site.

1. How should I deal with such links?
2. Will deleting the links solve the issue?
3. Also, will hotlinking use up the servers entry process?

Answer (score 3):

To stop hotlinking you can add the following to your .htaccess file. Replace example.com on line 3 with your own domain name.  Also add or remove any file extensions on line 4

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|zip|rar|mp3)$ - [F]
```

Maybe you prefer some mischief and want to serve alternate content when hotlinking is detected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.example.com/backside.gif [R,L]
```

Comment: Mischief? I prefer outright havoc and chaos! ;-) I had a similar problem where a very popular commercial media site hot linked several images way back in the day. I changed the images to a porn image and wha la! Problem solved. Although, it took about a week for them to notice. Their customers noticed quickly. What cracks me up is people wrote articles (news - before the days of blogs) about the incident. It became sorta famous. I guess I shoulda felt flattered? Nah. Not me. I am a stinker! Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc I have also used a porn image with great, rapid and hilarious success.  I considered that as an example in the answer, but was trying to keep the SE standard above mine. :o)

Comment: That cracks me up. Great minds think alike!

Comment: I like what you did there.